# Array values and insert in ksh

Tags: arrays, shell, unix, ksh

I've got an array which returns the `data_type` of a table read from a file. For example:

```
filed1 VARCHAR2
filed2 INTEGER
```

etc.

Now I have to do an `insert` in the same table for a backup. This procedure would be dynamic so I came up with this:

```
ENDROW=""
while read ENDROW;
do  
    tmp=${ENDROW##*@#;}
          field1=`printf "%s\n" "${tmp%%@#;*}"`
    tmp=${ENDROW##*@#;}
          field2=`printf "%s\n" "${tmp%%@#;*}"`

    *and here the insert in the table*
done
```

I created the array because I need it to find the `data_type` of each field so I can understand if the values need to be quoted (`''`) or not. How can I "connect" the array to this? The shell would be able to understand that the first value of the array is `VARCHAR2` and quote with `''` as part of the `insert`.

---

Oh ok now i understand.. Thanks! However..if my array is like:

```
field1                VARCHAR2
field2                NUMBER
field3                VARCHAR2
field4                DATE
field5                TIMESTAMP(6)
field6                DATE
field7                DATE
field8                CHAR
```

the function will be:

```
function format {
case "${typeof[$1]}" in
    VARCHAR2) printf '"%s"\n' "$2" ;;
    NUMBER)  printf "%d\n" "$2" ;;
    DATE)  printf "%d\n" "$2" ;;
    CHAR)  printf "%d\n" "$2" ;;
    *) print -u2 "don't know about field '$1'" ;;
    esac
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd do something like this -- i assume you have an array named `typeof` that maps the field name to the datatype:

```
function format {
    case "${typeof[$1]}" in
        VARCHAR2) printf '"%s"\n' "$2" ;;
        INTEGER)  printf "%d\n" "$2" ;;
        *) print -u2 "don't know about field '$1'" ;;
    esac
}

while read ENDROW;
do  
    tmp=${ENDROW##*@#;}
    field1=$( format field1 "${tmp%%@#;*}" )
    tmp=${ENDROW##*@#;}
    field2=$( format field2 "${tmp%%@#;*}" )
    # and here the insert in the table
done
```

Comment: now i try it.. But can you explain me the function please? What exacly do?

Comment: it says: field1: The specified number is not valid for this command.

Comment: First, tell me what you have here: "I've got an array which returns the data_type of a table read from a file." -- Do you have an array variable in the ksh script?

Answer (score 0):

well, first of all i made a select with a spool to extract what i need. Then i made the array from that file created from the spool in this way:

```
i=0
while read str
do
arr[$((i=i+1))]=$str
done < ${file}
```

The array contains :

```
field1                VARCHAR2
field2                NUMBER
field3                VARCHAR2
field4                DATE
field5                TIMESTAMP(6)
field6                DATE
field7                DATE
field8                CHAR
```

Ok?

---

I was thinking the array would be:

```
arr[field1]="VARCHAR2"
arr[field2]="NUMBER"
arr[field3]="VARCHAR2"
arr[field4]="DATE"
arr[field5]="TIMESTAMP(6)"
arr[field6]="DATE"
arr[field7]="DATE"
arr[field8]="CHAR"
```

This is an associative array, using a string instead of an integer as the index. You would do

```
typeset -A arr
while read key value; do
    arr[$key]=$value
done < ${file}
```